# use pojos generated from yang to configure device using odl netconf client

Tags: opendaylight

I managed to generate Pojos from yang files, using OpenDayLight YangTools.

Next stage i managed to import netconf client to my application (using gradle), how do i use the generated pojos with netconfClient in my application to configure a device?

Comment: The OpenDaylight documentation suggests that features like the Netconf Client must be installed in a running Karaf container and invoked in that context.  Did you find a way to invoke a method on a remote Netconf server and get an answer without using Karaf?

Answer (score 3):

Would be good if you explain what you want to achieve so I can help you more accurately, 
but if you want to configure your box programmatically using yang, you need to follow the steps below:

1. From yang models generate your runtime configuration classes
   (this    is what you have now)
2. Write some logic to call those generated classes and create an
   object which defines your configuration. For instance, setting up a
   BGP config, you need to start from the router, bgp, address family,
   neighbour, and so on.
   The object will follow your device Yang model, or the 'openconfig' one like here:
   https://github.com/openconfig/public/blob/master/release/models/bgp/openconfig-bgp.yang
3. After you have generated your 'configuration instance', then you
   need to serialise it (convert to XML)
4. Use a netconf client (look for ncclient) to send it to the box.

If you are not much fussed about the language, I would suggest you use

https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/ydk-py

which has examples already.

A more Opendaylighty approach is,

1. Start a maven project and yangtools in it, https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Startup_Project_Archetype#Starting_your_.27example.27_project_for_the_first_time
2. Load netconf southbound application
3. Add your yang models you want (optional)
4. Do a maven build so it generates the API for you (you will have
   access to the device API directly).
5. Then what extra you can do is to implement the logic where the
   provider classes are and provide your own API.

Hope this helps

Comment: i added another question so it will be more clear ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647215/can-i-use-opendaylight-functionality-same-as-jnc)
thanks for your answer anyways!

Comment: I have a remote VM simulating my device. If i go with the opendaylighty approach, how do i make odl be aware/connect to the VM?

Comment: Well ok if this helped tick it and I will reply to next one? Or move them under same tree of questions

Comment: unfortunately it didn't solve my problem, yet i am still trying to make it work, can you guide me how can i make odl connect to a vm, not localhost?

Comment: what is the VM specifically? if by VM you mean a virtual vendor device, then you can potentially use a number of southbounds such as netconf or SNMP plugins to connect. If you want to connect to the control plane, such as BGP, you need to use and configure that plug in. If the VM is a normal operating system with some daemons of protocls running, then you need to specific, hope this helps

Comment: In the first scenario, would you please explain step 3, how to serialize a configuration instance as XML?