# can i use opendaylight functionality same as jnc?

Tags: opendaylight

I want to write an application to configure network element using netconf and I’m looking for an open source netconf client I can use to achieve it.

I already tried and succeeded doing so using Jnc. the problem is that jnc doesn’t support netconf 1.1 and I’m looking for another solution.

Is it even possible to use the same functionality via opendaylight?
In jnc i converted yang files to java classes, filled them and then configured the device. what steps should i do in opendaylight for the same functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Yangtools in opendaylight covers what JNC provides, in addition to generating restconf API automatically.

In general there are a number of steps you need to follow as I have explained here:
[use pojos generated from yang to configure device using odl netconf client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51627804/use-pojos-generated-from-yang-to-configure-device-using-odl-netconf-client/51638411#51638411)

Once you go through creating a maven project, you can import the yang models you want to use in to the project. 
For instance, lets say you have yang models from a vendor like Nokia or Cisco, you need to place them in a folder within the maven project (please use the boiler plate provided by Maven Archetype to generate one), and then you need to declare this folder in the features.xml file of the project.
When you build your project, you will end up with java codes from the yang models.
Now its your turn to write some logic, and use those generate java classes in your provider code.
And to use Netconf, or any protocol for that matter, you need to import those additionally in to your project, which then would be accessible via the MDSAL.

Please note, from my personal experience with ODL, its not easy to understand it without getting hands on. I would suggest starting from simple projects from the links I provided in my other post, and then adding features one by one to get to know the tool.
Hope this helps.